# Silicon Labs - EFM32GG Series 0 - Letimer not working

Tags: cortex-m

I am trying to get the LETIMER0 on the STK-3700 (EFM32GG990F1024) working as a normal timer (start timer (single run), wait for timeout, interrupt->applicationCB).

the timer tough is not counting. can you help me?

Unfortunatelly, silicon labs has no example on their github page for this, just examples for pwn, pulse and other things i cannot use.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include "em_chip.h"
#include "em_cmu.h"
#include "em_emu.h"
#include "em_letimer.h"
#include "leds.h"

volatile uint32_t msTicks; /* counts 1ms timeTicks */

void SysTick_Handler(void)
{
  msTicks++;       /* increment counter necessary in Delay()*/
}

void Delay(uint32_t dlyTicks)
{
  uint32_t curTicks;

  curTicks = msTicks;
  while ((msTicks - curTicks) < dlyTicks) ;
}

void initLetimer(void)
{
  LETIMER_Init_TypeDef letimerInit = LETIMER_INIT_DEFAULT;

  // Enable clock to the LE modules interface
  // #define cmuClock_CORELE cmuClock_HFLE
  CMU_ClockEnable(cmuClock_HFLE, true);

  // Select LFXO for the LETIMER
  CMU_ClockSelectSet(cmuClock_LFA, cmuSelect_LFXO);
  CMU_ClockEnable(cmuClock_LETIMER0, true);

  // Reload COMP0 on underflow, pulse output, and run in repeat mode
  //  bool                       enable;         /**< Start counting when init completed. */
  //  bool                       debugRun;       /**< Counter shall keep running during debug halt. */
  //  bool                       rtcComp0Enable; /**< Start counting on RTC COMP0 match. */
  //  bool                       rtcComp1Enable; /**< Start counting on RTC COMP1 match. */
  //  bool                       comp0Top;       /**< Load COMP0 register into CNT when counter underflows. */
  //  bool                       bufTop;         /**< Load COMP1 into COMP0 when REP0 reaches 0. */
  //  uint8_t                    out0Pol;        /**< Idle value for output 0. */
  //  uint8_t                    out1Pol;        /**< Idle value for output 1. */
  //  LETIMER_UFOA_TypeDef       ufoa0;          /**< Underflow output 0 action. */
  //  LETIMER_UFOA_TypeDef       ufoa1;          /**< Underflow output 1 action. */
  //  LETIMER_RepeatMode_TypeDef repMode;        /**< Repeat mode. */
  letimerInit.enable = false;
  letimerInit.debugRun = false;
  letimerInit.rtcComp0Enable = false;
  letimerInit.rtcComp1Enable = false;
  letimerInit.comp0Top = false;
  letimerInit.bufTop = false;
  letimerInit.out0Pol = 0;
  letimerInit.out1Pol = 0;
  letimerInit.ufoa0 = letimerUFOANone;
  letimerInit.ufoa1 = letimerUFOANone;
  letimerInit.repMode = letimerRepeatFree;

#if 0
  LETIMER_CompareSet(LETIMER0, 0, 15);
  LETIMER_CompareSet(LETIMER0, 1, 50);
#elif 1
  LETIMER_TopSet(LETIMER0, 50);
#endif
  LETIMER_IntEnable(LETIMER0, LETIMER_IFC_COMP0|LETIMER_IFC_COMP1);

#if 1
  letimerInit.enable = true;
  LETIMER_Init(LETIMER0, &letimerInit );
#else
  LETIMER_Init(LETIMER0, &letimerInit );
  LETIMER_Enable(LETIMER0, true);
#endif
}

void LETIMER0_IRQHandler()
{
  // debug code only

  LED_Toggle(1);

  while(1)
    ;
}

int main(void)
{
  /* Chip errata */
  CHIP_Init();

  /* Setup SysTick Timer for 1 msec interrupts  */
  if (SysTick_Config(CMU_ClockFreqGet(cmuClock_CORE) / 1000)) while (1) ;

  /* Initialize LED driver */
  LED_Init();
  LED_Clear(0);
  LED_Clear(1);

  initLetimer();

  /* Infinite blink loop */
  while (1)
  {
    LED_Toggle(0);
    Delay(1000);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I miss this line in your code:

`NVIC_EnableIRQ(LETIMER0_IRQn);`

BTW: Example code is included in Simplicity Studio.